# Envoy proxy returning 'no healthy upstream' and/or ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE for ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net-core, docker-compose, envoyproxy

I'm trying to setup an example ASP.NET project that uses envoy to route between the secure and non-secure versions of the app. The application works fine in Docker on both http and https, but when I try to route to it through envoy I get 'no healthy upstream' on the http site, and ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE on the https site.

My envoy.yaml:

```
static_resources:

  listeners:
    - name: listener_http
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 80
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/admin"
                          direct_response:
                            status: 403
                            body:
                              inline_string: "Forbidden, yo"
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: exampleagg-http
    - name: listener_https
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 443
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/admin"
                          direct_response:
                            status: 403
                            body:
                              inline_string: "Forbidden, yo"
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: exampleagg-https
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                  - certificate_chain:
                      filename: /etc/https/aspnetapp.crt
                    private_key:
                      filename: /etc/https/aspnetapp.key

  clusters:
    - name: exampleagg-http
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: exampleagg-http
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: http://example-api/WeatherForecast
                      port_value: 80
    - name: exampleagg-https
      type: LOGICAL_DNS
      # Comment out the following line to test on v6 networks
      dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: exampleagg-https
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: https://example-api/WeatherForecast
                      port_value: 443
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              - certificate_chain:
                  filename: /etc/https/aspnetapp.crt
                private_key:
                  filename: /etc/https/aspnetapp.key
```

My docker-compose.yaml:

```
networks:
  envoy:
    name: envoy

services:
  api-gateway:
    image: envoyproxy/envoy:v1.23-latest
    container_name: api-gateway
    volumes:
      - ./ApiGateways/Envoy/config:/etc/envoy
      - ${USERPROFILE}/.aspnet/https:/etc/https/
    networks:
      - envoy
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
      - "8081:443"
    depends_on:
      - example-api
  example-api:
    image: ${REGISTRY:-hexsorcerer}/example-proxy-envoy:${PLATFORM:-linux}-${TAG:-latest}
    container_name: example-api
    volumes:
      - ${USERPROFILE}/.aspnet/https:/https/
    environment:
      ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT: Development
      ASPNETCORE_URLS: "https://+;http://+"
      ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT: 443
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password: "password"
      ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path: /https/aspnetapp.pfx
    networks:
      - envoy
    expose:
      - "80"
      - "443"
    ports:
      - "5000:80"
      - "5001:443"
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Services/Example/Example.API/Dockerfile
```

The Dockerfile for the example application:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src

# It's important to keep lines from here down to "COPY . ." identical in all Dockerfiles
# to take advantage of Docker's build cache, to speed up local container builds
COPY "ExampleEnvoyProxy.sln" "ExampleEnvoyProxy.sln"

COPY "Services/Example/Example.API/Example.API.csproj" "Services/Example/Example.API/Example.API.csproj"

#RUN dotnet restore "ExampleEnvoyProxy.sln"

COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/Services/Example/Example.API
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o /app

EXPOSE 80 443

FROM build AS publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Example.API.dll"]
```

I've been hacking away at this for days and made some good progress, but just can't quite get there. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After not getting any responses for a couple weeks, I was forced to keep hacking around on this and I finally figured it out.

I think the biggest problem with what I was doing was a misunderstanding about how proxy servers route traffic. I was attempting to route the incoming path '/' to a backed service path of '/WeatherForecast', but that's not how it works. Your incoming endpoint will be "passed along" to the backend service, it's simply the cluster that you choose to pass it to. This is probably clear to veterans but as someone who doesn't work on these often it wasn't obvious to me at first.

There was also an issue of certificates, and I ended up generating one for the app and one for envoy, each of which were different formats, that also had to be trusted on my machine. This took a little extra effort for the envoy cert, but it worked much better than trying to use a single cert for both.

I documented what I learned with some instructions and a fully working example [here](https://github.com/hexsorcerer/example-proxy-envoy).